# git-svn vcs switch: where are my branches?

Tags: git, git-svn

I converted a very large svn repository to a git repository with

```
git svn init svn/server/project --no-metadata
git svn fetch
```

This took the better part of two days to finish.

This repo should have quite a few branches but when I do "git branch" I get nothing but the master. They are listed under the branches directory, but shouldn't I see them with "git branch" as well?

"git branch -a" only shows master and remotes/git-svn.

Was it the --no-metadata switch that did this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When initializing the git repository you need to use either the  `--trunk`, `--branches` and `--tags` options or the `--stdlayout` option to `git svn init` in order to tell it the path to the directories to the `trunk`, `branches` and `tags` directories in the subversion repository.

See the [manual page for git-svn](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) for additional details.

Comment: I have read the manual page but I'm still not certain. So would "git svn init svn://server/project --stdlayout" be the correct command to transfer everything? Or use the those three separate parameters instead? Just want to make sure, as I said, it takes about two days to transfer the data so I wouldn't want to do it a third time...

Comment: Yes, `--stdlayout` should give you what you want if you have `trunk`, `tags` and `branches` directories according to the default subversion layout.  But if you really want to be sure everything works right, try setting up a small test subversion repo and try to convert that one before trying to convert the real repo again.

Comment: When I checkout a SVN Repository with git I use the command "git svn clone svn://server/project -T trunk -b branches -t tags" just to make sure I get everything I need. "--stdlayout" should work the same way.

Comment: I think i'll give svn2git a try, found that while reading through a heap of stuff on the subject. Seems like it should do the trick nicely provided the svn layout is standard. I have no idea since I'm not familiar with svn & wasn't involved with creating this repository.

Comment: Oh yes, svn2git did the trick and it worked much, much faster than git svn.